# zpl barcode Printing to Generic / Text Only from Chrome and IE

Tags: php, google-chrome, zebra-printers, zpl-ii

I'm trying to print ZPL Code generated by my web-interface to a Zebra printer(Zebra GK420d)configured as Generic / Text Only printer this works fine in firefox.In Chrome and IE it is not working. I am using latest IE and Chrome versions and my Operating system is windows 8. I cleared my cache and cookies and tried. But i am unable to print. Here is my sample zpl barcode like this.

```
^XA ^FWR ^FO 425,450^A0,20,30
^FH^FDCHEDDI_20JAGAN_20AIRPORT_20GUYANA_20OWN_20CLEARING^FS 
^FO 300,450^AD^BY2 ^BC,100,Y,N,N ^MD1 ^FO 300,450^A0,20,30^FH^FDDATE_3A14-10-2014^FS
^FO 200,450^A0,20,40^FH^FDLTX106970_2D1_281_29_2D_UGAC^FS ^XZ
```

Please help me how to resolve this problem.Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you know if the code is making it to the printer?  Put the printer into hex dump and send from the browsers that it is not working.  With the printer powered off, press and hold the feed button while you turn on the power.  The printer prints out a listing of its current configuration.  After Printing the label, the printer automatically enters a diagnostic mode in which the printer prints out a literal representation (ie. HEX DUMP) of all data subsequently received.  To exit the diagnostic mode and resume printing, turn off and then turn on the printer.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is, by default, you can't print directly to a Generic/Text-Only printer profile from the Chrome browser.  Chrome pre-processes/renders all prints, which takes away the raw text delivery to a printer.  It would actually render the characters of the text rather than sending the raw text itself.  There used to be an option to enable the Text-only setting in Chrome, but it was removed somewhere around version 22.

There is a project called JZebra/qz (https://code.google.com/p/jzebra/).  This will allow you to print to the Zebra printer from the Chrome browser.  This requires Javascript added to your site in the printing process code, and requires Java on the client's computer.  It will ask to install a little Java program to their computer to intercept and handle the special printing scenarios.  If your client doesn't have or want Java or the installed program on their machine, it won't work.  You can use the free/unsigned version of the program, but there is a cost if you want a digitally signed version of the consumer-downloaded Java application.